# ¿Alguien sabe por qué me marca error?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Buen día.

Estoy creando una base de datos con MySQL Workbench, pero al momento de crear el auto-incremento para las primary key en las tablas me lanza un error de sintaxis.
No entiendo muy bien el porque pero agradeciera mucho que me ayudaran a entender mi error, ya que anterior mente había usado la misma sintaxis para Microsoft SQL Server y no me había generado ningún error.

```
create database practica02;
use practica02;

Create table DEPTO (

--> Id_depto int identity (1,1),
Nomb varchar (20),
#REC int,
chimenea int,
lavaplatos int,
cocina_int int,
primary key (Id_depto),
foreign key (ID_INQUILINO) references INQUILINO(ID_INQUILINO),
foreign key (ID_CLASIFICACION) references CLASIFICACION (ID_CLASIFICACION));


Create table INQUILINO (

--> ID_INQUILINO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
NOMB VARCHAR(20),
NOMBRE INT,
RFC INT,
EDAD  INT,
TELÉFONO INT,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_INQUILINO));
```

Comment: Agrega por favor el mensaje de error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás usando `identity(1,1)` y eso es de SQL Server.

En Mysql es `auto_increment`:

```
ID_INQUILINO INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Recuerda que entre las bases de datos, aunque sean SQL, cada una tiene sus particularidades.